# Given a value, find the upper and lower values in sorted array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For example I have array x

```
x = [10, 100, 1000, 10000]
```

If I have the number 600, then how can I get the values 100 as the lower value and 1000 as the upper value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the input as sorted, we can use [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to get the index where `600` could be placed in that sorted order and then simply use the index and one-off shifted index to get the lower, upper limits upon indexing, like so -

```
idx = np.searchsorted(x,600)
out = x[idx-1], x[idx]
```

Sample run -

```
In [41]: x = [10, 100, 1000, 10000]

In [42]: idx = np.searchsorted(x,600)

In [44]: x[idx-1], x[idx]
Out[44]: (100, 1000)
```

We can also use [`bisect` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html), which I believe could be a bit faster -

```
import bisect

idx = bisect.bisect_left(x,600)
```

Comment: Good, but I would warn the OP to check for edge cases like when searching for values outside of the min and max of the array such as `0` or `10001`:   `idx = np.searchsorted(x, 0); x[idx-1], x[idx]` gives `(10000, 10)` and `idx = np.searchsorted(x, 10001); x[idx-1], x[idx]` gives `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Good point. OP needs to clarify on what's the desired lower, upper limits for those edge cases.

Comment: Thanks! I won't ever have a case where values are outside the min/max

Answer (score 0):

[Iterate over the list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements); check to see if the current number is greater than the test value; if it is [select this value and the previous value](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).
[enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) might make this easier.

Assumes a sorted list.